# How does one convert bayerRG12 to RGB888 image? (Baumer Camera)

Tags: image-processing, camera, pyqt, pixel

For what it's worth, I'm using trying to code a [baumer camera(txg50c model)](http://www.baumer.com/us-en/products/productfinder/?tx_baumerproductfinder_pf%5Burl%5D=%2Fpfinder_vision%2Fscripts%2Fproduct.php%3Fpid%3DTXG50c%26cat%3DIndustriekameras%26psg%3D%26language%3Den%26r%3D1%26ptk%3D%26sq%3D). The pixel formats available in this camera are BayerRG8, BayerRG12, Mono8, YUV411 Packed, and YUV422 Packed. I suppose the bayerRG12 (for your record, the documentation file says it uses 2 bytes per pixel) will work out.

Now, I'm trying to show the image using Pyqt4 but I keep getting crashes if I directly convert it to RGB888 (standard 24 bit image).

> self.qImg = QtGui.QImage(imageData.data, width,
>   height, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)

I've tried like QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB444, it works but it doesn't appear like what I want (the color in the image is messed up, on which i don't know why)
I tried Mono8/BayerRG8 on the camera with QtGui.QImage.Format_Indexed8 also, but it only showed black and white picture.

Comment: A Bayer format image only contains one (12-bit) value per pixel, while standard RGB requires 3 8-bit values per pixel. You need to first run a de-bayering filter to get R,G,B values for each pixel, then convert from 12-bit linear to 8-bit gamma-corrected. I suspect de-bayering is beyond the scope of a StackOverflow answer unless there's an existing library for it.

Comment: The problem has been solved. Apparently the SDK provides a way to convert RG12 into RGB. Thanks!